# Installing Graphics Driver Window 7 Dell Laptop

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card

When I try to install graphics driver this window appears and it never finishes until I kill process .I tried to install this driver so many times .

[image]

And  sometimes if it completed I see this window. I searched similar problem but could not get the solution .

[image]

Please help how I can solve this issue ?

Comment: The driver might not be compatible. Is Windows 32-bit or 64-bit? What's the laptop exact model?

Comment: It is Dell Inspiron and 64 bit .

Comment: If Win7 is grabbing and doing this install by itself try going out and grabbing the driver manually and installing from the .exe if it isnt an automatic install I suggest verifying that you have the correct option (go download again) and attempt again...oh, and make sure you dont have any other drivers installed...that could be a problem as well.

Comment: Ok @James I will try .

Answer (score 1):

It might be an Internet connection problem. Windows tries sometime to download the driver from Windows Update, but if you have an unstable Internet connection, it can fail.

In this case it is better to download the driver from the hardware manufacturer. There is multiple ways to do that :

1. The easiest : locate you machine model number, then go to Dell's support or driver download page, search for your laptop model and download the appropriate driver
2. Identify your chipset model number with the help of the laptop specs then go to the Intel Download Center and search the appropriate driver package
3. The hardest : Retrieve the PCI ID of the GPU by going to the Hardware Managment window (Right clic on Computer → Properties → Hardware Manager, then locate the Graphic card → Right clic → Properties → Details → Select something like Identification number in the drop-down list (2nd item) then note down the 4 characters after VEN and DEV). Then using a search engine, try to find what's your chipset model and go to the Intel Download Center and search the appropriate driver package.

It might be another problem, but still try to download and install the driver manually, it should succeed.

Comment: There is not internet problem, I have connection and it working properly and other option I will try .Thanks